# The file pom.xml gives an error on first line when using Spring boot version 2.4.3

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

I have created a spring boot starter project in eclipse IDE using the spring boot version 2.4.3. The default created pom.xml file shows an error "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/.m2e/connectors/m2eclipse-mavenarchiver/0.17.2/N/LATEST/" on first line.

If I change the version to 1.4.2.RELEASE, it works fine. But I need Apache Camel in the project and wanted to use the latest version of Spring boot project.

I tried to create the project even from start.spring.io, but when imported into eclipse it behaves the same way. Could any one please help me with this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Add these dependencies in your pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-servlet-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jackson-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-swagger-java-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot-starter.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: This did not work. Which version of Spring boot and Apache Camel were you suggesting?